# Diagonalizing a $3$x$3$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello, everyone. I'm having difficulty with this homework problem. I solved for the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors, but diagonal matrices can't have a zero in the diagonal. I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong for this problem?

Comment: see determinant is zero then one of the eigen values has to be zero.

Comment: This is just a diagonization problem.

Comment: A diagonal matrix has zeros *outside the diagonal*; the diagonal coefficients can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question you should ask yourself is why do you think diagonal matrices cannot have a zero in the diagonal? [*Ans*: They can. A quick jaunt to wikipedia or google will reinforce this claim].